# How i change this statement to dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I trying to change this to be dynamic but I stuck at the set of data..
Example, the statement

SELECT * FROM A
WHERE id IN (1,2)

and also 1,2 come from 
SELECT id FROM B 
WHERE type='%xxx%'

Statement above can return many number 
I try to declare @id but I have no idea

So, Have any idea? 
Thank you for suggestion :)

Comment: Suggestion one, please rewrite the question so I can read it.

Comment: Your going to want to clarify the question.  I cant understand what your asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id FROM B
     WHERE type='%xxx%')
```

This is called a [subquery](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-subquery.htm).

EDIT: When using a subquery is not an option and you want to use a variable, you can declare a temporary table and join table `A` with that table.

```
DECLARE @C table (id int)

INSERT @C (id) 
SELECT id FROM B
WHERE type='%xxx%'

SELECT A.* 
FROM A INNER JOIN @C c ON A.id = c.id
```

Comment: Thank, but if in this case I can't use subquery(for some reason) How i can declare @id for id IN (1,2) ?

Comment: I added a solution using a temporary table as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* FROM A 
INNER JOIN B
WHERE B.type='%xxx%'
AND A.ID = B.ID
```

Perhaps you can just use inner join, it should return you the result set that you looking at